# TextView grow height automatically android

Tags: android, textview

Example my Textview Android

[image]

```
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_comen"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"


    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"


    android:maxLines="2"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"


    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:background="@drawable/mensaje"

    android:text="-"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView2" />
```

This is the xml code of my textview which I want to automatically grow the height of agreement along the text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `layout_height` to **wrap_content** like below.

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and remove this line or set higher value

```
android:maxLines="2"
```

**Edit:** You may remove this line too (Thanks to @alisun)

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

Comment: And also I suppose android:ellipsize="marquee" will be redundant without maxLines and with wrap_content. So need to remove it too.

Answer (score 3):

Replace 90dp by wrap_content  or match_parent